# Using WholeFileInputFormat with Hadoop MapReduce still results in Mapper processing 1 line at a time

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

To expand on my header in using Hadoop 2.6.. and need to send whole files to my mapper instead of a single line at a time. I have followed Tom Whites code in the Definitive Guide to create WholeFileInputFormat and WholeFileRecordReader but my Mapper is still processing files 1 line at a time. Can anyone see what I'm missing in my code? I used the book example exactly from what I can see. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

WholeFileInputFormat.java

```
public class WholeFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat <NullWritable, BytesWritable>{

@Override
protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file){
    return false;
}

@Override
public RecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable> createRecordReader(
        InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    WholeFileRecordReader reader = new WholeFileRecordReader();
    reader.initialize(split, context);
    return reader;
}
```

}

WholeFileRecordReader.java

```
public class WholeFileRecordReader extends RecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable> {
private FileSplit fileSplit;
private Configuration conf;
private BytesWritable value = new BytesWritable();
private boolean processed = false;

@Override
public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    this.fileSplit = (FileSplit) split;
    this.conf = context.getConfiguration();
}

@Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    if (!processed){
        byte[] contents = new byte[(int) fileSplit.getLength()];
        Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
        FSDataInputStream in = null;
        try{
            in = fs.open(file);
            IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);
            value.set(contents, 0, contents.length);
        }finally{
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
        }
        processed = true;
        return  true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public NullWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    return NullWritable.get();
}

@Override
public BytesWritable getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    return value;
}

@Override
public float getProgress() throws IOException {
    return processed ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException{
    //do nothing :)
}
```

}

And the main method for my Mapreduce

```
public class ECCCount {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.out.printf("Usage: ProcessLogs <input dir> <output dir>\n");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(ECCCount.class);
    job.setJobName("ECCCount");

    //FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    WholeFileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(ECCCountMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(SumReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    System.exit(success ? 0 : 1);
  }
```

}

And my Mapper for good measure. Right now it simply returns the value its given as a test case to see if its returning a line or whole file

```
public class ECCCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
@Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      context.write(new Text(value), new IntWritable(1));
  }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Ramzy's input I found my error and was able to get the whole file passed with the following changes

In my main method I needed to specify the InputFormatClass I needed to use.

```
job.setInputFormatClass(WholeFileInputFormat.class)
```

and my Mapper needs to expect the correct types as input

```
public class ECCCountMapper extends Mapper<NullWritable, BytesWritable, Text, IntWritable>{
```

Those two changes successfully sent a byte[] of the entire file to my mapper where I manipulate it as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Issue can be the input format of mapper. You have LongWritable and text. however in the example mentioned, they have used NullWritable, BytesWritable because that is what a WholeFileInputFormat  is having. Also, you need to give **job.setInputFormatClass(WholeFileInputFormat.class);** in Job class(main method). Hope it helps, and Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I wasn't paying enough attention to my types. Ill post my solution thanks to that.

Comment: Happy coding. You can use useful flag, if it helped you. And accept answer later if it solved.

Comment: I dont think you need reputation to accept answer :)