# Inserting filename as rowkey using HBase MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

using Java API, I'm trying to `Put()` to HBase 1.1.x the content of some files. To do so, I have created WholeFileInput class (ref : [Using WholeFileInputFormat with Hadoop MapReduce still results in Mapper processing 1 line at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649590/using-wholefileinputformat-with-hadoop-mapreduce-still-results-in-mapper-process) ) to make MapReduce read the entire file instead of one line. But unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to form my rowkey from the given filename.

Example:

**Input:**

file-123.txt

file-524.txt

file-9577.txt

...

file-"anotherNumber".txt

**Result on my HBase table:**

Row-----------------Value

123-----------------"content of  1st file"

524-----------------"content of 2nd file"

...etc

If anyone has already faced this situation to help me with it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure I understand well, you just want to put file in HBase? If you want to do that, just read the file as a byte array and put it in Hbase

Comment: @Whitefret yes but not only, I have solved the issue of how to put the entire file in HBase, now, it's about generating the rowkey from the filename. I have written a method for that, method taking filename as input and return a string (=myRowKey) but I cannot visualize how can I call this méthod from my mapper function

Comment: you do not need a mapper function for that, except if you have big file in which case you shouldn't be using HBase

Comment: few questions: what is the size of the file and what do you intend to do with them when stored? do you want a mapper job to distribute the reads?

Comment: @Whitefret actually this question is the continuity of my previous post (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894265/proper-ways-to-put-xml-into-hbase ) my files aren't big at all, but numerous, so, I have decided to use a mapper function which take as input file-content and PUT (of HBase) as the output

Comment: oh sorry didn't recognize you ^^. I have to look at how to do it with mapper and if I find something I will tell you

Comment: considering the size of your file, I am not sure a mapper function is well suited for you case. in hadoop, you want to deal with file that are bigger than 60 MB. here, you could just bulk load your xml into Hbase

Comment: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/

Comment: you still have to do a mapper though

Comment: @Whitefret thanks I will readapt it to my own needs

Comment: @mttb12 : if you want file name as access pattern to access rowkey to retrieve file content I gave the answer for that. In my experience it is best suit for you

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
rowkey
```

can be like this

```
rowkey  = prefix + (filenamepart or full file name) + Murmurhash(fileContent)
```

where your prefix can be between what ever presplits you have done with your table creation time.

For ex :

```
create 'tableName', {NAME => 'colFam', VERSIONS => 2, COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY'}, 
    {SPLITS => ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7']}
```

prefix can be any random id generated between range of pre-splits.

> This kind of row key  will avoid hot-spotting also if data increases. 
>   & Data will be spread across region server.